# How to set UIReturnKeyType for iPhone Bundle.settings?

Tags: iphone, settings.bundle

in `Settings.bundle` I define my [app preferences](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW5) with different fields, some of them are text fields. However when I press on a text field to edit it the keyboard slides up.

My problem is that the keyboard does not disappear. It has a return button. Clicking on it the cursor just jumps to the next text field.

I have seen some keyboards that have a `done` button.

Is it possible to set [**UIReturnKeyType**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIReturnKeyType) in Settings.bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the list of keyboard type in iPhone.

```
 UIKeyboardTypeDefault,
   UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,
   UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,
   UIKeyboardTypeURL,
   UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,
   UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,
   UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,
   UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,
   UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,
   UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable
```

Here is the link to Apple Documentation link.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardTypeDefault

you can set the anyone of above .

```
self.myTextView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interface builder you can choose in the inspector what keyboard you want.
If it is a NumberPad , there is no "done" or "return" button.
For to add this button , look into here : http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key